# err_connection_reset when one particular client is trying to login into my App

Tags: javascript, https, dns, ip

One of the clients is getting this error in Chrome and Safari when trying to log into my app. the weird part is that my App is working for all other clients except this one particular client. When they are trying to log into the app with correct credentials they get this error on chrome console:

```
POST https://frefghrfbg  net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

on the UI it just doesn't do anything. I have checked my code I am not blocking any IP or anything and the client has also check at their end and they say it's my app's API that's blocking their IP.

I am not sure where to start and how to fix this error.

APP STACK:
UI Angular
Services Node Js
Domain Blue host
Deployed on AWS